# My project encounters an error while running. Can anyone solve this problem?

Tags: react-native, axios, typeerror

```
  state = { HomePage: [] };

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://xxxxxx')
  .then(response => {
    this.setState( {HomePage: response.data})
  })
}
   renderImage() {
     return (
        this.state.HomePage.map(Music => <Text>{Music.Name}</Text>)
      )
    }
```

I called state in this section but when the run project get error

```
              <View style={{flex:1}}>
                {this.renderImage()}
              </View>
```

**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.HomePage.map')**

Comment: what is the structure of your response. what does response.data log

Comment: Show us where u map your values ... seems like your state might not be set before mapping